# Not able to view lookup icon on visualforce page using Lightning Design

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I am using lightning design classes for visualforce pages. Each and everything is working perfectly only the issue is that i can't see the search icon for lookup field.
Code:

PO Box Address

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup filters in lightning are not same as the lookup filters in clasic. In lightnign It is like a search box.

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lex_gaps_limitations_search.htm

To create search box you can follow the following link-

https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-lookup-in-lightning-component/

Comment: Do you mean that i will have to create a lightning component for that?

Comment: @NileshBorse It will be better if you do

Comment: I have found one more solution over it....if you set standardStyleSheet attribute of apex:page as true then you can see lookup icon in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code, but based on my experience, I had to add "/apexpages/slds/latest/" to the icon url path:

For instance:

```
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#switch" />
```